# Postgresql. How to update column with range of integers from from 0 to last row that satisfies WHERE criteria

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a next table sample, called `userz`:

```
+----+---------------+----------+
| id | sort_position | type     |
+----+---------------+----------+
|  1 |            -5 | admin    |
|  2 |            -3 | customer |
|  3 |             1 | customer |
|  4 |             8 | employee |
|  5 |           200 | customer |
+----+---------------+----------+
```

With `Mysql` If i want to make `sort_position` of all `customer` type to start from 0 and `++` until the last row that satisfies `WHERE` criteria, i can do next:

```
SET @i=-1; 
UPDATE userz 
SET sort_position=@i:=@i+1 
WHERE type = "customer" ORDER BY sort_position;
```

and i would receive expected result:

```
+----+---------------+----------+
| id | sort_position | type     |
+----+---------------+----------+
|  1 |            -5 | admin    |
|  2 |             0 | customer |
|  3 |             1 | customer |
|  4 |             8 | employee |
|  5 |             2 | customer |
+----+---------------+----------+
```

as you see all customers are now assigned with correct `sort_position` of 0,1,2

But since i'm working with postgre i need to reach same with it. What i tried so far:

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
   i integer := -1;   
BEGIN  
   UPDATE userz 
   SET sort_position=@i:=@i+1 
   WHERE type = "customer" ORDER BY sort_position;
END $$;
```

and i have errors around `=@i:=@i+1` , tried different formatting that i googled like `=i:=i+1` but still no luck.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is `Postgres`, why do I see `MySQL` tag????  They're completely 2 different products.

Comment: The error is probably caused by your `ORDER BY`.  It doesn't make sense to `ORDER BY` in `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL;

```
update userz k
set sort_position = 
     (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by sort_position)-1 rnum
         from userz src
        where src.type ='customer'
          and id = k.id)
```

Comment: It will update the sort_position for type customer starting sequence from 0 to nth.